# Is there a way to keep CoreData in Sync with a Server API even when the App is in Background/Suspended/Terminated states?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, synchronization, chat

I'm trying to make an App that's exactly like WhatsApp, so far the biggest limitation is that when a user re-opens the App after a while, and goes to a `Conversation View`, new `Message`s that were sent during the time the App was in Background/Suspended or Terminated **states** have to be recovered from a Server (API), and this causes a potential delay for new messages showing up in the `Conversation View`.

How can I achieve permanent **Sync** of an App with a server API? I'm kind of sure apps like WhatsApp manage to do this, because `Message`s never appear to be downloaded whenever you **re-open** the App after a while, right?

What is the right way to sort of Mimic this type of behavior? I really want to learn how to perform this kind of "advanced" synching and I don't know where to get started. Again, my goal is to try to avoid server-downloads of new `Message`s when a user re-enters a `Conversation View`for example (because that would be bad UX)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You cannot really get **perfect** sync. You can get close. Use push notifications to let your app know that there are messages to be retrieved. You can also do *some* background processing to get updates.

Comment: Yeah, I'm beginning to realize it can't be perfect. But, Is it expected that you should download 'some' data (Messages) upon entering the ViewController they belong to? Or should it happen sometime before like in an AppDelegate callback?

Comment: You could load all the messages for all conversations when the app is brought to the foreground. Then they are already loaded when entering the conversation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your app will need push notifications.  This is a **must have** for apps like this.

On the server, when you know that there are new messages, send a push notification to the app. This will let the app know that there are messages to read.  At this point the app can badge the app icon, pop an alert and show on the notification screen. The user controls how notifications appear.

Details about notifications here: 
https://developer.apple.com/notifications/

Your app can load all messages when it gets the notification.

iOS apps do have some limited options for background processes: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html

Comment: Hello there, this appears to be exactly what I'm looking for. The sections on: "Using Push Notifications to Initiate a Download" and "Fetching Small Amounts of Content Opportunistically" seem promising. You don't happen to have some Swift samples around by any chance? Thanks a lot, sir.

Comment: Sorry. I don't have any code that would be helpful for this.  There are many examples of push notifications. Write some code.  If you get stuck, open a new question.